# Express Swagger Generator Image upload

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using `express-swagger-generator` to create swagger documentation. I have written an image upload services. I would like to upload image directly via swagger ui page.

Here is my doctrin. How it would be possible ?

```
/**
 * @typedef ImageUpload
 * @property {string} image.required - The image to be uploaded (binary)
 */

    /**
     * @route POST /image-upload
     * @group ImageUpload
     * @summary endpoint for uploading an image
     * @param {ImageUpload.model} ImageUpload.body.required
     * @type multipart/form-data
     * @consumes multipart/form-data
     * @returns {object} 200 - An array of image info
     * @returns {Error}  default - Unexpected error
     *
     */
```

It just gets an area to write body as a string.
I would like to achieve this:
[image]